# Websocket : Handshake status 200 OK

Tags: python, websocket

Our WebSocket client developed in Python Version python3 connects to our internal WebSocket server using ://wss protocol and we are able to exchange data via WebSocket. Works well.
However, when our WebSocket client is connecting to our internal WebSocket server (or) external WebSocket server using ://ws protocol, the handshake exceptions. The error that we receive:

```
2024-03-11 18:19:12,166 [INFO] # connectWS Exception.. wsConnect count
2024-03-11 18:19:12,166 [ERROR] Try: 4, ConnectWs    :Handshake status 200 OK
```

Code Snippet that initiates the WebSocket connection:

```
ws = websocket.create_connection(configFile['WebSocketBackend'])
```

The URL of the WebSocket server is retrieved from the configfile. Details of these can be provided upon the engagement.